# Pass an object methods and call those methods outside of function. Random Password Generator

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

New to javascript have a password generator project

I'm trying to access the passwordInfo object outside of the generatePasswordInfo function.
I want to pass the passwordLength so I can generate a random character for the length of the requested password.

I capture the password length via the getpasswordLength variable, store it in passwordInfo. I think this is where I"m having a problem returning the value in passwordInfo.

I take the generatePasswordInfo function which contains passwordInfo and store that in a variable passwordIncludes. Then I iterate though the length of passwordIncludes to grab a random character for each index. Then push that to an empty array createdPassword.

```
// numbers array
var numbersChar = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
//lowercase array
var lowerCaseChar = [
  "a",  "b",  "c", "d",  "e",  "f",  "g",  "h",  "i",  "j",  "k",  "l",  "m",  "n",  "o",  "p",  "q",  "r",  "s",  "t",  "u",  "v",  "w",  "x",  "y",  "z"
];
//uppcase array
var upperCaseChar = [
  "A",  "B",  "C",  "D",  "E",  "F",  "G",  "H",  "I",  "J",  "K",  "L",  "M",  "N",  "O",  "P",  "Q",  "R",  "S",  "T",  "U",  "V",  "W",  "X",  "Y",  "Z"
];
// special char array
var specialChar = [
  "@",  "%",  "+",  "\\",  "/",  "'",  "!",  "#",  "$",  "^",  "?",  ":",  ",",  ")",  "(",  "}",  "{",  "]",  "[",  "~",  "-",  "_",  "."
];

// Assignment code here
function generatePasswordInfo() {
  var getPasswordLength = parseInt(prompt("Choose number of characters for your password."));
  if(getPasswordLength < 8 ) {
    alert("A minimum number of 8 characters requried.");
    generatePassword();
  }
  if(getPasswordLength > 128 ) {
    alert("A Maximum number of 128 characters requried.");
    generatePassword();
  }
  if (isNaN(getPasswordLength)) {
    alert("Invalid input. Please insert a number.");
    generatePassword();
  }
  
  //Confirm including lowercase letters
  var includeLowerCase = window.confirm("Click Ok to include lowercase characters");


  //Confirm including uppercase letter
  var includeUpperCase = window.confirm("click Ok to include uppercase characters");


  //Confirm including numbers
  var includeNumbers = window.confirm("click Ok to include numbers");


  //Confirm including special characters
  var includespecial = window.confirm("click Ok to include special characters");


  if (!includeLowerCase && !includeUpperCase && !includeNumbers && !includespecial) {
    alert("Minimum of 1 character type needed.");
    return;
  }
  
 //stores password Info in object
var passwordInfo = {
  passwordLength: getPasswordLength,
  includeLowerCase: includeLowerCase,
  includeUpperCase: includeUpperCase,
  includeNumbers: includeNumbers,
  includespecial: includespecial
};

return passwordInfo; 
}

// Get a random character from an array
function getRandomChar(arr) {
  var randomChar = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  var selectedChar = arr[randomChar];

  return selectedChar;
}


function generatePassword() {
  
  // passwordInfo object
  var passwordIncludes = generatePasswordInfo();
 
  //store created password
  var createdPassword = [];

  // Array to store types of characters to include in password
  var availableCharacters = [];

  // adds array of lower characters to array of available characters
  if(passwordIncludes.includeLowerCase) {
    availableCharacters = availableCharacters.concat(lowerCaseChar);
  }

  // adds array of upper characters to array of available characters
  if(passwordIncludes.includeUpperCase) {
    availableCharacters = availableCharacters.concat(upperCaseChar);
  }

  // adds array of numbers to array of available characters
  if(passwordIncludes.includeNumbers) {
    availableCharacters = availableCharacters.concat(numbersChar);
  }

  // adds array of special characters to array of available characters
  if(passwordIncludes.includespecial) {
    availableCharacters = availableCharacters.concat(specialChar);
  }

  // Iterate through the password length, get random index from the array of available characters
  for (var i = 0; i < passwordIncludes.length; i++) {
    availableCharacters = getRandomChar(availableCharacters);

    // add characters to password array
    createdPassword.push(availableCharacters);
  }
  
  return createdPassword.join("");
  

}


// Get references to the #generate element
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  passwordText.value = password;

}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

here's a jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/v74aqxtL/

Comment: `passwordInfo` is an object with strings as keys and functions as values, these functions are not being invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code

1. When looping to generate the right number of chars you're doing `for (var i = 0; i < passwordIncludes.length; i++) {` when that should say `for (var i = 0; i < passwordIncludes.passwordLength; i++) {`
2. You're redefining the available characters with `availableCharacters = getRandomChar(availableCharacters);` make it something like `var c = getRandomChar(availableCharacters)` and concatenate `c` into the generated password

```js
// numbers array
var numbersChar = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
//lowercase array
var lowerCaseChar = [
  "a",  "b",  "c", "d",  "e",  "f",  "g",  "h",  "i",  "j",  "k",  "l",  "m",  "n",  "o",  "p",  "q",  "r",  "s",  "t",  "u",  "v",  "w",  "x",  "y",  "z"
];
//uppcase array
var upperCaseChar = [
  "A",  "B",  "C",  "D",  "E",  "F",  "G",  "H",  "I",  "J",  "K",  "L",  "M",  "N",  "O",  "P",  "Q",  "R",  "S",  "T",  "U",  "V",  "W",  "X",  "Y",  "Z"
];
// special char array
var specialChar = [
  "@",  "%",  "+",  "\\",  "/",  "'",  "!",  "#",  "$",  "^",  "?",  ":",  ",",  ")",  "(",  "}",  "{",  "]",  "[",  "~",  "-",  "_",  "."
];

// Assignment code here
function generatePasswordInfo() {
  var getPasswordLength = parseInt(prompt("Choose number of characters for your password."));
  if(getPasswordLength < 8 ) {
    alert("A minimum number of 8 characters requried.");
    generatePassword();
  }
  if(getPasswordLength > 128 ) {
    alert("A Maximum number of 128 characters requried.");
    generatePassword();
  }
  if (isNaN(getPasswordLength)) {
    alert("Invalid input. Please insert a number.");
    generatePassword();
  }
  
  //Confirm including lowercase letters
  var includeLowerCase = window.confirm("Click Ok to include lowercase characters");


  //Confirm including uppercase letter
  var includeUpperCase = window.confirm("click Ok to include uppercase characters");


  //Confirm including numbers
  var includeNumbers = window.confirm("click Ok to include numbers");


  //Confirm including special characters
  var includespecial = window.confirm("click Ok to include special characters");


  if (!includeLowerCase && !includeUpperCase && !includeNumbers && !includespecial) {
    alert("Minimum of 1 character type needed.");
    return;
  }
  
 //stores password Info in object
var passwordInfo = {
  passwordLength: getPasswordLength,
  includeLowerCase: includeLowerCase,
  includeUpperCase: includeUpperCase,
  includeNumbers: includeNumbers,
  includespecial: includespecial
};

return passwordInfo; 
}

// Get a random character from an array
function getRandomChar(arr) {
  var randomChar = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  var selectedChar = arr[randomChar];

  return selectedChar;
}


function generatePassword() {
  
  // passwordInfo object
  var passwordIncludes = generatePasswordInfo();
 
  //store created password
  var createdPassword = [];

  // Array to store types of characters to include in password
  var availableCharacters = [];

  // adds array of lower characters to array of available characters
  if(passwordIncludes.includeLowerCase) {
    availableCharacters = availableCharacters.concat(lowerCaseChar);
  }

  // adds array of upper characters to array of available characters
  if(passwordIncludes.includeUpperCase) {
    availableCharacters = availableCharacters.concat(upperCaseChar);
  }

  // adds array of numbers to array of available characters
  if(passwordIncludes.includeNumbers) {
    availableCharacters = availableCharacters.concat(numbersChar);
  }

  // adds array of special characters to array of available characters
  if(passwordIncludes.includespecial) {
    availableCharacters = availableCharacters.concat(specialChar);
  }

  // Iterate through the password length, get random index from the array of available characters
  for (var i = 0; i < passwordIncludes.passwordLength; i++) {
    var c = getRandomChar(availableCharacters);

    // add characters to password array
    createdPassword.push(c);
  }
  
  return createdPassword.join("");
  

}


// Get references to the #generate element
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  passwordText.innerHTML = password;

}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #f9fbfd;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  color: hsl(206, 17%, 28%);
}

.card {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 2px 8px 0px;
  color: hsl(206, 17%, 28%);
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

.card-header::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #e7e9eb;
  height: 2px;
}

.card-body {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.card-footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.card-footer::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #e7e9eb;
  height: 2px;
}

.card-footer::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: hsl(360, 91%, 36%);
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 1px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 1px
    0px;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin: 16px 16px 16px 20px;
  padding: 14px 34px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
  background: #c0c7cf;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

#password {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 85px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 2px dashed #c0c7cf;
  border-radius: 6px;
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media (max-width: 690px) {
  .btn {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 16px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
  }

  #password {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .btn {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <header>
        <h1>Password Generator</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h2>Generate a Password</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <textarea
            readonly
            id="password"
            placeholder="Your Secure Password"
            aria-label="Generated Password"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <button id="generate" class="btn">Generate Password</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're actually (/first) problem is you should be referencing:

```
passwordIncludes.passwordLength
```

Instead of:

```
passwordIncludes.length
```

Within your 'for' loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < passwordIncludes.length; i++) {
```